# flutter: How to modify the color of a Container in a large number of Containers

Tags: flutter

sorry for not being able to explain what I really want to mean in the title, but you will understand in the picture below and the code is what I have done.
[image: click then color change]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class ChangeColor extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _ChangeColorState();
  }
}
class _ChangeColorState extends State<ChangeColor> {
  List<Color> colorList = List(3);
  int selectedId = 0;
  void selectById(int id) {
    setState(() {
      selectedId = id;
    });
  }
  void renderColor(int selectedId) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
      if (i == selectedId) {
        colorList[i] = Colors.teal;
      } else {
        colorList[i] = Colors.red;
      }
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget myContainer(int id, Color color) {
      return InkWell(
        child: Container(
          width: 100, height: 100,
          color: color,
        ),
        onTap: () {
          selectById(id);
        },
      );
    }
    renderColor(selectedId);
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              myContainer(0, colorList[0]),
              myContainer(1, colorList[1]),
              myContainer(2, colorList[2]),
            ],
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So my question is if I have a large number of `Container`s and even don't know the exact number, I can't give every `Container` an id and maybe can't use `List`, so how to solve the problem.
Actually this happens sometimes, for example in `Calendar` app. Thanks for any suggestion or criticism.

Comment: I wonder if my question has any problem? I got downvote several times. If I have any mistake in asking a question please let me know, I will improve myself. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this way?

```
Widget myContainer(int id) {
      return InkWell(
        child: Container(
          width: 100, height: 100,
          color: selectedId == id ? Colors.teal : Colors.red,
        ),
        onTap: () {
          selectById(id);
        },
      );
    }
```

It is a full code I fixed from your code.
And I recommend to move a 'myContainer' to outside of build().

```
class _ChangeColorState extends State<ChangeColor> {
  List<Color> colorList = List(3);
  int selectedId = 0;
  void selectById(int id) {
    setState(() {
      selectedId = id;
    });
  }

  Widget myContainer(int id) {
    return InkWell(
      child: Container(
        width: 100,
        color: selectedId == id ? Colors.teal : Colors.red,
      ),
      onTap: () {
        selectById(id);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            height: 100,
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return myContainer(index);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: A good optimization, thank you very much.  But can you figure out a solution that can help me give up using `id`? id seems not suitable if there are quantities of `Containers`.

Comment: As you said that you will build many container, at that time maybe you will use ListBuilder or some widget. At that time using iterable index instead id.

Comment: @byhuang1998 I changed full code for your request. I made a many container like 'Row'. and it work's same before.